# Dynamic Addition of Items to a List in Spring Thymeleaf Using Fragments

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I want to implement a feature where a button allows users to add new children to the parent's child list (see below). I've managed to make it work using the code provided, but I find it less than ideal that I have to set the HTML in two places. This means that when new member variables are added, I have to update both the HTML and the JavaScript.

My preferred solution would be to have the child represented as its own fragment, which could be dynamically pulled in via a GET request. However, I believe this might not be feasible as the fragment would lack context of the current index.

Another approach I considered is to copy the existing HTML, increment the index, and insert it afterwards.

```java
public class Parent {

    private String parentName;
    private List<Child> children;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}

public class Child {

    private String childName;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class YourController {

    @GetMapping("/create-parent")
    public String showCreateParentForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("parent", new Parent());
        return "createParentForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create-parent")
    public String createParent(@ModelAttribute Parent parent) {
        // Process the submitted parent object (including its list of children)
        // ...

        return "redirect:/create-parent-form";
    }
}
```

```html
<form th:action="@{/create-parent}" th:object="${parent}" method="post">

        <label for="parentName">Parent Name:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{parentName}" />

        <!-- Iterating over the list of children -->
        <div th:each="child, childStatus : *{children}">
            <label th:for="${'children[' + childStatus.index + '].childName'}">Child Name:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{children[__${childStatus.index}__].childName}" />

            <!-- You can add other child-related fields here -->
        </div>

        <!-- Button to add a new child -->
        <button type="button" onclick="addChild()">Add Child</button>

        <button type="submit">Create Parent</button>
    </form>
```

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        function addChild() {
            var newChildIndex = document.querySelectorAll('[th\\:id^="children"]').length;
            var newChildHtml = '<label for="children[' + newChildIndex + '].childName">Child Name:</label>' +
                               '<input type="text" th:field="*{children[__' + newChildIndex + '__].childName}" />';
            document.querySelector('[th\\:each="child, childStatus : *{children}"]').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newChildHtml);
        }
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```